# JavaFx8 3 TextField . Input on one textfield, updates the other one

Tags: javafx, textfield

I have three Textfields tfNet, tfVat and tfGross.
*(for my app i do all with java money. in this example with double.)*

What I want:
When i change tfNet it should update

```
tfGross.setText("" + (Double.parseDouble(tfNet.getText()) * 
                   (1 + Double.parseDouble(tfVat.getText()) / 100)));
```

When i change tfVat

```
tfNet.setText("" + (Double.parseDouble(tfGross.getText()) / 
                   (1 + Double.parseDouble(tfVat.getText()) / 100)));
```

When i change tfGross

```
tfNet.setText("" + (Double.parseDouble(tfGross.getText()) / 
                   (1 + Double.parseDouble(tfVat.getText()) / 100)));
```

I tried with a TextFormatter for all three Textfield but got stuck in an loop.

Then tried with NumberBinding, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

What is the JavaFx way to do this?

1) Bind a SimpleDoubleProperty to the Textfield and addListener to DoubleProperty?

or

2) Or setOnAction on the TextField?

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand the third requirement. When you change `tfGross`, you want to then change `tfGross`? Doesn't that just mean you don't want the user to be able to edit `tfGross` at all?

Comment: you are right. i edit the third one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add listeners to each of these TextField's `textProperty()` and apply the logic in it.

For example, in case you want to add a change listener to `tfNet`, you can write :

```
tfNet.textProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // Proper checks for Text as Double
    tfGross.setText("" + (Double.parseDouble(tfNet.getText()) * 
                   (1 + Double.parseDouble(tfVat.getText()) / 100)));
});
```

Comment: This gives trouble while writing. Since there is a loop with `tfGross.textProperty....`. But when i put it in `if(tfNet.isFocused()) {tfGross.setText....` it works the way it should.

Comment: If a listener changes the state of the notifier, it will lead to recursion. My suggestion would be to avoid it.

Comment: Since your question is not very clear, I would take a wild guess and say what you want is to add listeners to `tfGross` and `tfVat` to change the third textfield `tfNet`. So, you must add listeners to the first two textfields and  not to the third one.